# How do I access a variable from another class in Xamarian?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm calculating the percentage of Males and Females from the total user gender by allowing the user to input the number of each gender from the source class. I also want to "carry" the variables from the source file "POF" and "POM" into the target class, how would I go about doing this? As you can see I've attempted to bind the values into the target labels but nothing...

**The source .XAML Form I want to get the varibles from**

```
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout>
            <Label Text="Change Amount of Male Users"/>
            <Entry x:Name="MaleUsersEntry"></Entry>

            <Label Text="Change Amount of Female Users"/>
            <Entry x:Name="FemaleUsersEntry"></Entry>

            <Button Text="Calculate" Clicked="Calculate_Button"></Button>

        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
```

**The source .cs Class**

```
public partial class HomePage : ContentPage
    {
        public double POF { get; set; }
        public double POM { get; set; }

        public HomePage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Calculate_Button(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string maleUsersString = MaleUsersEntry.Text;
            string femaleUsersString = FemaleUsersEntry.Text;

            double maleUsersDouble = 65.0D;
            double femaleUsersDouble = 35.0D;

            try
            {
                double.TryParse(maleUsersString, out maleUsersDouble);
                double.TryParse(femaleUsersString, out femaleUsersDouble);
            }
            catch (FormatException)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Please Input Digits." + maleUsersString + "&" + femaleUsersString + " are not numbers.");
            }

            double totalUsers = maleUsersDouble + femaleUsersDouble;

            double PercentageOfFemales = (femaleUsersDouble / totalUsers) * 100;
            double PercentageOfMales = (maleUsersDouble / totalUsers) * 100;

            PercentageOfFemales = Math.Round(PercentageOfFemales, 2);
            PercentageOfMales = Math.Round(PercentageOfMales, 2);

            POF = PercentageOfFemales;
            POM = PercentageOfMales;

        }
    }
```

**The Target .XAML Form I want to bind the varible to**

```
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout>
            <Label Text="The percentage of the User being Male is: " FontSize="Small"/>
            <Label Text="{Binding POM}" FontSize="Large"/>

            <Label Text="The percentage of the User being Female is: " FontSize="Small"/>
            <Label Text="{Binding POF}" FontSize="Large"/>

            <Button Text="Change Metrics" Clicked="UserChange_OnClicked"/>
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
```

**The Target .cs Class**

```
    public partial class OutputPageExt : ContentPage
    {
        double POM;
        double POF;
        public OutputPageExt()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            HomePage viewModel = new HomePage();
            this.POM = viewModel.POM;
            this.POF = viewModel.POF;
        }
    }
```

Comment: You could create a singleton model which contains `POM` and `POF` property, then you can generate it in any-one class and use it in any-other classes.

Answer (score 1):

If you navigate from **HomePage** to **OutputPageExt** , you could pass the current **HomePage** as a parameter .

```
public OutputPageExt(HomePage page)
{
   InitializeComponent();
   
   this.POM = page.POM;

   BindingContext = this;

}
```

And in HoemPage

```
 this.Navigation.PushAsync(new OutputPageExt(this));
```

Comment: How would I represent the ouytput in the .xaml page? Text = "{Binding POM}" or something else as it's saying it "No DataContext for POM"? Thank you for your response aswell, sorry for the delayed response

Answer (score 1):

You could create a new public class called Variables.cs, for example, and define the variables there.

Then both your HomePage and OutputPage classes can access them as Variables.POM

Answer (score 1):

**Method:1**
You can access the variable with two methods make a generic static class and assign value to this static variable and then access anywhere ..where you want.

**Method:2**
And here is the way to pass value when you navigate

> Navigation.PushAsync(new HomePage (val));

Make page code behind parametrized  constructor Like

```
public partial class HomePage : ContentPage
    {
        public double POF { get; set; }
        public double POM { get; set; }
       public double ReceivedValue { get; set; }


        public HomePage( Double val) //Here is to Receive the value
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            ReceivedValue =Val;
        }

        private void Calculate_Button(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string maleUsersString = MaleUsersEntry.Text;
            string femaleUsersString = FemaleUsersEntry.Text;

            double maleUsersDouble = 65.0D;
            double femaleUsersDouble = 35.0D;

            try
            {
                double.TryParse(maleUsersString, out maleUsersDouble);
                double.TryParse(femaleUsersString, out femaleUsersDouble);
            }
            catch (FormatException)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Please Input Digits." + maleUsersString + "&" + femaleUsersString + " are not numbers.");
            }

            double totalUsers = maleUsersDouble + femaleUsersDouble;

            double PercentageOfFemales = (femaleUsersDouble / totalUsers) * 100;
            double PercentageOfMales = (maleUsersDouble / totalUsers) * 100;

            PercentageOfFemales = Math.Round(PercentageOfFemales, 2);
            PercentageOfMales = Math.Round(PercentageOfMales, 2);

            POF = PercentageOfFemales;
            POM = PercentageOfMales;

        }
    }
```

Comment: Sylas Coker, I would suggest to go with above Method 2. If you are using MVVMCross, MVVMLight, etc., kind of library then you can pass as navigation parameter https://www.mvvmcross.com/documentation/fundamentals/navigation

Comment: Thank you, my computer was broken because of the android emulator but i'm currently working on it using your example, thank you!